# How does the execution occurs in c++?

Tags: c++

```
if(condition1 and condition2){
   //body
}
```

If condition1 turns out to be false, will c++ compiler check for condition2 or will it directly return false?

Comment: In c++ if you have 2 conditions or more with **and** operation between them and the first condition is false. The second one will not be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and C++ does use it: if `condition1` is false, `condition2` will not be checked.